# Smithchart affects me the axes of other tikzpiture graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, axis

Smithchart affects me the axes of other `tikzpicture` graphics. Place the *x* axis up, it does not allow to move the *x*-axis.

I've already tried everything and just basic smithchart affects it. It is not a solution to move the `xticklabel`, since it does not fit well.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmmm... you'll have to supply more information for the community to be able to help you. Can you provide some visuals and explain how you're currently working in Smithchart? This may be something that needs to be raised with the software tool developers, for example.